# What size wire feeders do I need

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding

I have 100 Amp service. I can't determine the wire size but it appears to be 6/3 feeder's.

My furnace is 14000 watts 240V at 60Amp.  I have a 980sq ft home with a electric dryer, a refrigerator 20 Amp, 2 20amp receptacles in the kitchen2bathrooms, 1 20amp outside receptacle, a electric flat top oven and range,
a 30amp water heater, all the receptacles  and lights are 15amp,1 220v 30amp window a c.

The furnace has 2 60amp breakers  installed on it
and is controlled by a 40 amp 240 V breaker in my panel.
I noticed the breaker gets quite warm but does not blow when furnace is on in Ohio.

**Are my wires good for this load**

The feeders are short by 10 feet of making it into the panel box, it had a 50Amp temporary cord the rest of the way

The cord was 50amp with A 50amp receptacle in a metal box with no connectors and no conduit it burned up on one side of the cord  after a sewer back up last year it is burned up on one side and  very corroded.

What would be the best way to repair the feeder's and get them into my main panel box directly?

The feeder's run 30ft in conduit from the outside disconnect
come up 3 feet out of the ground in no conduit they are are 3 single insulated wires under the mobile home.

How would I connect 3 feeder wires to them  put it in a weatherproof box and run it 10feet into the main panel witch has a 100amp disconnect at the meter
and main panel.

No ground,  how should I add a ground rod and ground the system.

Are the grounds and neutrals supposed to be bonded and mixed and bonded to the service panel. I am trying to get the mobile home park owner to repair this as I rent the lot.
It was this way when I bought the home it started with a flood under my home last year

Finally the cord shorted out, the cord is 6/4 but the green wire goes no where and is not connected in the receptacle box.

The home is a 1978 single wide.I don't know when it was installed on this lot, I have been here 8 Years

What would be the best way to proceed

Am I right that the park owner should do the repairs
as the whole park sewer backed up under my home  where do I as the
Owner become responsible for electric hook up that was damaged

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Mobile homes normally have a 50 amp service and that would be closer to the wire size you have. Definitely not a 100 amp service but your panel inside may be a 100 amp panel but the breaker outside will be a 50.  As far as who is responsible that is a legal issue and that would be off topic. I can tell you that in most places you are responsible if plugged in. 
As this is a duplicate of your earlier question I vote to close

Comment: @EdBeal I think OP has a manufactured home as in "double-wide", not a mobile home as in "plug it in at KOA". 14,000 watt heaters are a misfit for an RV.

Comment: @harper  the op has shown this to be a “mobile home” connection with #6 wire in the feeder almost with identical questions and a “78 single wide” not an RV in this one.  I understand your limited experience yet again, There are still many parks with mobile homes axles underneath and the minimum was a 50 amp. not a KOA type of mobile but ~14’ wide x 70’ that’s 980 sf.  most parks require a hard line connection. I have connected both usually the plug in style is for shorter term occupancy’s. But the op shows the plug in the other question.  Could he have a larger feeder sure, a smaller heater?

Comment: If you're saying OP's laundry list of large electric appliances including range, 30A A/C and a 14,000 watt electric furnace is a good fit for a 50A service and #6 wire, then it illustrates how little I know about electrical!

Comment: The. main disconnect at the meter is 100amp the panel inside the house is 100amp the cord to the receptical are both rated at 50amp

Comment: What about a grounding system
 From the disconnect on
If you all say it will work then ok